# STM32 BlueNRG GAP Central Device Name not Accessable

Tags: stm32, bluetooth-gatt, bluenrg

I'm using a NUCLEO-L476RG devkit with the X$NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 expansion board.

I've configured my application as central device and start a scan.
I've also configured my mobile to send advertising packets using the "nRF Connect".
On receiving the advertising report of my mobile, I'm connecting to it.

When I'm trying to Read the Generic Access (0x1800) Device Name (0x2A00).
The nRF app then just shows an idle cursor while waiting for data from the central device and then gets disconnected.

When configuring the devkit as peripheral and starting the connection from the mobile everything works fine.

I've also tried the "universal central" example provided by STM, to try and read its device name attribute. But there my mobile gets immediatly disconnected with timeout.

From the looks of the Code both applications look the same for initialisation, scanning and creating an connection.

Comment: "then gets disconnected" - how long does "then" take? Instantly? After a second? After 10? Do you check any error conditions of anything? Any return values with errors?

Comment: For the disconnection problem:
It's the STM32 universal central example without any modification.
The example creates a connection on user input und then trys to read the available services. During this process, the `hci_disconnection_complete_event()` is thrown with the reason `BLE_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT (0x08)`
I havn't measured the time, but the `aci_gatt_disc_all_primary_services()` can't even finish in time.

Comment: For the problem with my own implementation, the `hci_disconnection_complete_event()` is not even called. On the devkit just nothing happens in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem seems to be related to the "nRF Connect" app on the mobile, as I've now two devkits connected to one another and am able to read a characteristic from the central device.

Also the connection to the "universal example" provided by STM works fine with a devkit periphal.